# Text input data does not show in php out put

Tags: php, html

I am trying create simple  script where text input data will be stored in text file through php.Html part working fine but php code is not  showing any output and nothing is written in text file. Here is my code,
HTML part

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <LINK REL="Stylesheet" TYPE ="text/css" HREF="info.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <form style="" method="post"   action="personalinfo.php">
           <label for="inputname">Name:</label><input id ="inputname" name="iname" input type="text"/>
           <br/>
           <br/>

           <label for=""="inputaddress">Address:</label><input id="inputaddress" name="iaddress" INPUT type="text"/>
           <br/>
           <br/>
           <label for="inputcity">City:</label><input id="inputcity" name="icity" type="text" />
           <br/>
           <br/>
           <label for="inputstate">State:</label><input id="inputstate" name="istate" type="text" />
           <br/>
           <br/>
           <label for="inputzip">Zip Code:</label><input id="inputzip" name="izip" type="text" />
          <br/>
          <br/> 
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['iname']))
            {
                $name=$_POST['iname'];
                $address =$_POST['iaddress'];
                $city =$_POST['icity']; //the data
                $state=$_POST['istate'];
                $zip=$_POST['izip'];
                $data= "$name|$address|$city|$state|$zip \n";

                //open the file and choose the mode
                $fh = fopen("pinfo.txt", "a");

                fwrite($fh, $data); 

                fclose($fh);
                print '$name';
            }
            ELSE
            {
                PRINT"NOThing";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what basic debugging have you done? What error messages are returned? Lack of effort from your part here I think...

Comment: Have you tried dumping your $_POST vars?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with your

FROM

```
<label for="inputname">Name:</label><input id ="inputname" name="iname" input type="text"/>
```

to

```
<label for="inputname">Name:</label><input id ="inputname" name="iname" type="text"/>
```

remove **input** keyword, it only needs to be with `<input`, you are using it twice.

Comment: Hey Nomi Thanks For replying to my question. I was able to solved the problem by saving both page  with php extension.

Answer (score 0):

Remove input, change it into

```
<label for="inputname">Name:</label><input id ="inputname" name="iname" type="text"/>
```

I have done some changes in your php code

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //print_r($_POST);  
    $name=$_POST['iname'];
    $address =$_POST['iaddress'];
    $city =$_POST['icity']; //the data
    $state=$_POST['istate'];
    $zip=$_POST['izip'];

    $data = $name."|".$address."|".$city."|".$state."|".$zip;

    //open the file and choose the mode

    $fh = fopen("pinfo.txt", "a");
    print_r($_POST);
    fwrite($fh, $data); 
    fclose($fh);    
}
else {
    echo "Nothing";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It will work fine. Learn some PHP Basics from http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Hello Shafeeq I was able to solve the problem by saving both file with  php extension. Thanks for your input.